# undefined method `per' for #<Customer::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f6ef6d11b60> for rails_admin gem and will_paginate-bootstrap gem on admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate, rails-admin

I installed 'rails_admin' gem for an admin panel. I already have 'will_paginate-bootstrap' gem installed.
[image]

When i click on a model name, I get this error
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Create a kaminari.rb in app/config/initializers and,

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

as you have will_paginate enabled, create will_paginate.rb in initializers and,

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
        def total_count() count end
        def first_page?() self == first end
        def last_page?() self == last end
      end
    end
    module CollectionMethods
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
end
```

This should work for rails_admin with will_paginate